# What is the difference between Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Server Live?

Tags: ubuntu

What is the difference between Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Server Live? I've had a good look around on the topic and there doesn't seem to be any clear information.

I can't seem to find a simple to understand description of the differences... any ideas?

Comment: Is this in the list of downloads? Because that sounds like a Live CD vs one meant to do the install, instead of trying it out before installing.

Comment: @Davidw Can't remember where exactly I downloaded the Live version from, but it will have been somewhere on the Ubuntu site

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are referring to the difference between the two server installer images:

- `ubuntu-18.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso`
  *Server install image for 64-bit PC (AMD64) computers (standard download)* and
- `ubuntu-18.04.1-server-amd64.iso`
  that also has versions for for different platforms: 64-bit ARM, PowerPC64 and IBM System z.

The difference is in the installers, and it's explained in BionicBeaver [Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Server_installer):

> The next generation [Subiquity](https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/subiquity) server installer, brings the comfortable
>   **live** session and speedy install of Ubuntu Desktop to server users at
>   last.
>
> N.B., If you require multipath, full-disk encryption, or the ability
>   to re-using existing partitions, you will want to continue to use the
>   alternate installer which can be downloaded from
>   http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/
>
> As of 18.04.1, the Subiquity server installer now supports LVM, RAID, vlans, and bonds.

According to Ubuntu forums, there are also more [differences between 18.04 "live" and "alternative"](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390785):

> 1. Changing the hostname will revert back to the original name after reboot on an install using "live" unless the following is changed:
>
>    Edit `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` and change `preserve_hostname` to `true`
> 2. On a "live" install, the following mount exists:
>
>    ```
>    /dev/loop0 88704 88704 0 100% /snap/core/4486
>    ```
> 3. On the "live" install the settings for auto updates are in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` while on "alternative" install
>      they are in a different config file (just grep `/etc` for
>      `"Update-Package-Lists"` string)
> 4. The "live" install asks the user on the first login to install a language pack:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install language-pack-en
>    ```
> 5. The `cloud-init` package is not installed by default with the "alternative" ISO but it is with the "live" ISO.

Comment: This list of differences doesn't provide me enough information to make an intelligent choice because a list of feature changes is interesting. But a description of the impact of each change and the consequence of following one path or the other can be enormously difficult to anticipate. That's the real answer. For example, the boot drive has one partition in Standard, but two in Live. But the key is the fact that Ubuntu in 20.04, promotes the 'live server', but hides the links to the standard server.

Comment: for me, the critical distinction is the live version is missing the components necessary for configuring an unattended installation.

Comment: Does the non-live still exist? I can't find any downloads of e.g. Ubuntu 20.04 server, that is not "live".